# Swift 3 - Connecting to MySql

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to connect my app to a mySQL serve, however I'm always getting the following error:

```
2016-11-28 18:27:32.987401 Fun iOS App[12725:473105] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 2 Connection has no connected handler
2016-11-28 18:27:32.988626 Fun iOS App[12725:473118] PAC stream failed with
2016-11-28 18:27:32.990092 Fun iOS App[12725:473105] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 2
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.58.6/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178
(lldb)
```

I'm trying load data into a tableview called tableView. It also has a cell with an identifier "cell"

This is my code so far:

```
  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var values:NSArray = []

    var count = 0;
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        get();
    }

 func get(){

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.helpmewastetime.com/service.php")
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)

        values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let maindata = values[indexPath.row]

        return cell;

    }
```

Can you please help me solve this error and explain what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: The actual error is "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." Your JSON file may be invalid or corrupt.

Comment: could you paste here what is your server response?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is related to your error, but I highly recommend to use a dispatch queue to download your data:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.helpmewastetime.com/service.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
    values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
 }
```

Also, you are missing the `numberOfRowsInSection` function, and are not displaying anything in your cell; you should do something like:

```
let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = maindata.title // or whatever your data structure is
```

Comment: still getting the same problem. For the second part I didn't add it yet(was waiting to solve that first error)

Comment: Ok. What I recommend is that you look at the actual error message (`JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set`) and search if you can find any info on that.